# Single plug for headphones and microphone - enable only the microphone

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, headphones

In my laptop I have a single plug for headphones and microphone together. I have a headset, but I want to plug it but only use its microphone, and want the sound to come out of the laptop's speakers. Is there a way to do it in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Windows comes with a feature to set a certain speaker/microphone as default.

- Open the control panel.
- Navigate to sound control panel. *(System > Sound > Sound Control Panel(right sidebar))*
- Playback Tab: Click the speaker you want to use. *(The default speaker is likely your in-build speaker, if not set your in-build/external speaker as default device, you can also disable the in-build/external speaker so the sound always goes to your headphone)*
- Recording tab: Click the Microphone you want to use and set it as default device.

You should now hear the music output trough the speaker of your choice and have only the microphone working at your headphone.

Comment: The only outbound sound option I have is the speakers, even when I jack my headphones